# How to represent by two classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have been asking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260159/223687) where I have got an answer that says:

```
We're not in JavaScript - objects don't have to be dictionaries. This could be well-represented by a class for product, and a class for product size.
```

I have been trying to contact but no luck yet however I did manage to go through chat and got the response:

```
look at this - this is a size
  
"[EU 40](https://testing/shgz?pid=16002&tkn=3381a6fdc2bf2675b42e756c6dc668e5&ipa=87783)': 1,

@dataclass
class ProductSize:
name: str
link: str
quantity: int

* have a list of class instances
* in your ProductSize dataclass, make a @classmethod constructor that accepts a dictionary and returns a class instance
```

However my problem is that my knowledge is not good enough to yet understand the issue and what the person means to be able to proceed my problem.

Currently how my code looks like is:

```
import json
import re
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from typing import ClassVar, List, Match, Optional

import attr
import requests
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

from config import configuration
from lib.utils import get, normalize_input


@attr.dataclass
class ProductPage:
    store: ClassVar[str] = "Shoezgallery"
    link: str = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
    price: Optional[str] = None
    image: Optional[str] = None
    pid: Optional[str] = None
    token: Optional[str] = None
    sizes: Optional[dict] = attr.ib(factory=dict)
    webhook: str = "mixed"
    delay: int = 0
    shortcut: List[str] = [
        '[Login](https://www.shoezgallery.com/en/authentification?back=my-account)',
        '[Cart](https://www.shoezgallery.com/en/commande)',
        '[Checkout](https://www.shoezgallery.com/en/authentification?back=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shoezgallery.com%2Fen%2Fcommande%3Fstep%3D1&display_guest_checkout=1)',
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def get_sizes(doc: Optional[Match[str]], pid: Optional[str], token: Optional[str]) -> dict:

        try:
            data = json.loads(doc.group(1))

            return {
                f"[EU {get_sizes}](https://testing/shgz?pid={pid.attrs['value']}&tkn={token.attrs['value']}&ipa={att})": get(values, 'quantity')
                for att, values in data.items()
                if get(values, 'quantity') > 0
                for get_sizes in get(values, 'attributes_values').values()
            }
        except JSONDecodeError:
            return {}

    @classmethod
    def from_page(cls, link: str) -> "ProductPage":
        with requests.get(url=link) as response:
            if not response.ok:
                return cls(
                    link=link
                )

            doc = HTMLParser(response.text)

        name = doc.css_first('h1[itemprop="name"]')
        price = doc.css_first('span[itemprop="price"]')
        image = doc.css_first('img[itemprop="image"]')
        pid = doc.css_first('input[name="id_product"]')
        token = doc.css_first('input[name="token"]')
        sizes = re.search('var\s*combinationsFromController\s*=\s*(.*?);', response.text, re.M | re.S)

        return cls(
            link=link,
            name=name and name.text().strip(),
            price=price and price.text().strip().replace("'", ""),
            image=image and image.attributes.get('src'),
            sizes=sizes and cls.get_sizes(sizes, pid, token),
        )

    @property
    def payload(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "store": self.store,
            "link": self.link,
            "name": self.name or self.link.split("/")[-1],
            "price": self.price or "Not found",
            "image": self.image or "Not found",
            "sizes": self.sizes or {},
            "shortcut": self.shortcut,
            "webhook": self.webhook,
            "delay": self.delay
        }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    payload = ProductPage.from_page(link="https://www.shoezgallery.com/en/p16002-air-pegasus-83-nike-dj6892-001")

    print(payload)
```

and I wonder what can I do to achieve where I have a class for the product and a class for product size?

Comment: You don't have to rewrite your whole application because someone on the internet told you to use X instead of Y. Actually, your code as posted on CR is perfectly fine.

Comment: @georg Thanks, that is true. It just that for me I also are willing to learn and understand what he meant as well. It doesnt mean that I might end up doing what he says of course and im pretty happy on what I have achieved here but there is stuff I wished I could improve example that I dont need to use the the payload (That is dict) but instead doing something like payload.name, payload.price etc etc but then I dont seem to get all the values that are in payload dict compare to the return of cls(...) inside `from_page` but thats probably another problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own classes to represent custom data types. You can try reading [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp).

The generic area you want to read up on is called *Object Oriented Programming*. I'm sure you will find plenty to help you on the topic.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the information! But if I understood it correctly. He mentioned to have two classes but is that even possible to do and share the data between each other? As my `from_page` function does the request and I dont really see a point to do another class that also does a requests to just get the sizes. Unless im thinking incorrectly now?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie Anything is possible my friend :) It's a very deep topic you're delving into. I'd recommend researching OOP and clean coding principles first.

Comment: Oh wow, so the code isn't even good :'( Haha I thought I have done a good job but... I will try to read it but im still having abit hard time to understand what I am actually looking regarding the code reveiw I got